# Is it better to use uint8_t or char to represent binary data arranged in bytes?

Tags: c++

I like uint8_t because I feel that the intent (binary data, not characters) is better expressed. However, there are many char-based I/O functions which I might want to call. Just wondering if there's a best practice that folks conform to out there? This is my first foray into byte-level I/O.

Comment: A side note: you might be interested in C++14's binary literals: e.g. `0b00110101`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem with `char` is that it may be either a signed type (with a range of at least -127..+127) or an unsigned type (with a range of at least 0..255).

`unsigned char` is better than plain `char` for binary byte-oriented data.

`uint8_t`, if it exists, will have the same range and representation as `unsigned char`, and will *probably* be just another name for the same type.

Note that C++ (like C) defined a *byte* as the smallest addressible storage unit on a given system. It's *at least* 8 bits, and will probably be exactly 8 bits on any system you're likely to use, but it's allowed to be wider. The macro `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<stddef.h>` or `<cstddef>`, tells you the number of bits in a byte.

If you want to absolutely guarantee that you're using 8-bit bytes, either query the value of `CHAR_BIT` or use `uint8_t`. If bytes are bigger than 8 bits, then `uint8_t` won't exist (because there will be no type that meets its requirements).

Comment: So if you tried to port your program to platform where uint8_t does not exist you'll get an error which is correct behavior, over using bigger (because of that platform) char type ?

Comment: @bluesm: Only you can decide whether a getting a compile-time error or using a type that's too big is preferable. Using `uint8_t` means you'll know about the problem as soon as you try to compile. (Using `uintleast8_t` might be reasonable, depending on your requirements). But manipulating octets (8 bits by definition) on a system with `CHAR_BIT != 8` is going to be tricky in any case.